# What to do when python don't want to run a previous working program?

Tags: python-3.x

This script was running ok before I upgraded from 15.1 to 15.2 (LInux LEAP)

```
import pixellib
import time
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

segment_image=instance_segmentation()
segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
start = time.time()
segment_image.segmentImage("thisone.png",output_image_name="thisone_ryzen.png",show_bboxes = True)
end = time.time()
print(f"Inference Time: {end-start:.2f}seconds")
```

Now I have these errors:

```
sirius:/cours/journalisme/ia/ryzen7 # ./rigolade.py 
./rigolade.py: line 4: from: command not found
./rigolade.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./rigolade.py: line 6: `segment_image=instance_segmentation()'
```

Answer (score 0):

It used to run when you did `python3 ./rigolade.py`, but now you're doing `./rigolade.py`. By doing that, and not including a shebang line for Python, it's trying to execute the script as shell commands. Add a shebang line like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

to the *very* top of the file (very first line) and it should work. Or just run it using `python3` (or `python`, environment dependent) explicitly like you used to.

The reason the error doesn't occur until the third line is because many Linux distros actually ship with a tool named `import` (often a screenshot snipping tool); you might want to delete the `pixellib` and `time` files it just left in your working directory. But `from` isn't a recognized command, and the parentheses don't match your shell's syntax rules, so it starts erroring out at that point.

Comment: Thank you the problem was that python wasn't poiting to python3 that is required to use pixellib...